# SQL Select statement multiple rows

Tags: sql, select

I have 2 tables as follows.

Project table.

```
ID      ProjectID      description      etc. 
1       4849           aaabbbb          etc.
```

Invoice table.

```
ID      ProjectID      InvoiceNo      InvoiceDate      amount
1       4898           1234           01.01.01         200
2       4898           5678           02.02.02         475
```

What I need is the following.

```
ProjectID      Description      Invoicedate      amount
4898           aaabbbb          02.02.02         675
```

I think I am over thinking it but need help.

Comment: most tables have multiple rows. So your title is not really informative

Comment: Your ProjectIDs in this example aren't equal.

Comment: Sorry they are ment too all show 4898

Answer (score 2):

Use grouping with a sum:

```
SELECT i.projectId, description, MAX(invoiceDate), SUM(amount)
   FROM invoice i
   JOIN project p ON p.projectId = i.projectId
   GROUP BY i.projectId;
```

I elected to use `max` to get the latest invoice date for each project.  Assuming that is what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT Project.ProjectID, Description, MAX(InvoiceDate), SUM(Amount)
FROM Project JOIN Invoice ON Project.ProjectID = Invoice.ProjectID
GROUP BY Project.ProjectID, Description
```

If your InvoiceDate isn't an actual `DATETIME`, you will need to convert it for this to work or use another way of getting max of `InvoiceDate`.

SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb4f9/2).  Note that I changed the ProjectIDs in your Invoice table to match the one in your Invoice table.

Comment: When i do max invoicedate it just returns #Name and returns two rows still

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention invoicedate is a datetime

Comment: The value for `MAX(InvoiceDate)` is `#Name`?  Are you sure that `InvoiceDate` is a `DATETIME`, then?  Also, can you post the exact query and results?

Comment: Its really wierd but it is set as a datime field when i look at the table desin but still comes back as #Name? Any ideas but thanks to your input it has now become one single row

Comment: Sorted it, me being a muppet had not selected invoicedate as an alias

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  *,
  sum(amount) as amount
from
  Project as p
  inner join Invoice as i
    on p.ProjectID = i.ProjectID
group by ProjectID
```

the invoice date may vary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how you want to do the grouping, but it could be something like

```
SELECT project.ProjectID, project.description, MAX(invoice.InvoiceDate), SUM(invoice.amount) FROM project JOIN invoice ON project.ProjectID = invoice.ProjectID WHERE project.ProjectID = 4898 GROUP BY project.ProjectID
```